# odoo deleted module is still in list

Tags: magento, module, odoo

I recently installed odoo 8.0. I manually added a mangento connector module, this means I downloaded the module and installed it via the setup.py script. After updating the module list I correctly found the module in the module list in odoo as well. Now, I wanted to delete the module and deletet this module in any directory I found it. However, after clearing the cache, restarting nginx, restarting odoo, restarting the server alltogether I still get this module in the module list. I even searche the entire harddisk for files containing the module name. Still, even without finding any file containing "magento", I still get this module as result. I checked the addon folders several time. I start to think that I do not understand the principle of odoo...
can anyone help me? Why is this module still displayed, after all I learned odoo browses through all addon folders lookinf for module upon refreshing the module list, so there shouldn't be this module, correcT?

Thanks
 Peter

Answer (score 6):

1.) View the installed modules as a list instead of the default icon (kanban) mode. Button is on top right of module page.
2.) Select the check box next to mangento
3.) Click the more button at the top of the page

You will see a delete button in the drop down.